Multiple OR conditions in an AND formula
I'm trying to get a yes or no result from comparing certain items that could be the content of a cell (F2) with certain possibilities from (H2) and again from (K2).
If all the conditions are true then return a (YES). this is the formula I used. I get a data validation error.
=IF(AND(OR(F2=W2,F2=W3),
OR(H2=S2,H2=S3,H2=S5),
OR(K2=T2,K2=T4,K2=T5,K2=T8,K2=T10,K2=T11)),
"Yes","No")

If all conditions are true I expect a YES result.

Data validation needs a formula that returns True or False, not the text "Yes" or "No", so you'd remove the IF function and just keep the AND and everything inside it.

@Rory: or keep the IF and replace "Yes" by TRUE and "No" by FALSE :-)

Your formula does yield "YES" or "NO" (I just copied it into cell "A1" of a blank Excel worksheet), but in order to use it as a basis for data validation, you need to realise that such a formula should yield FALSE or TRUE, so I advise you to replace your formula by:

=AND(OR(F2=W2;F2=W3);OR(H2=S2;H2=S3;H2=S5);OR(K2=T2;K2=T4;K2=T5;K2=T8;K2=T10;K2=T11))), as proposed by Rory, or:
=IF(AND(OR(F2=W2;F2=W3);OR(H2=S2;H2=S3;H2=S5);OR(K2=T2;K2=T4;K2=T5;K2=T8;K2=T10;K2=T11));TRUE;FALSE), if you want to reduce the modifications to your formula.

